# Bootstrap 4 Scrollspy "position: relative" requirement

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, web-testing

From the website of bootstrap 4, it stated that in order to use Scrollspy, there are a few requirements. One of the requirement is

"Scrollspy requires position: relative on the element you’re spying on, usually the ."

However, it seems that Scrollspy works fine without body {position:relative} in the case of  is the element being spied

Using a Scrollspy example from w3school [w3schoolScrollspyexample](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_scrollspy&stacked=h)

Even if i delete body {position:relative} from style and hit the run button, the Scrollspy function still works.

Here is the w3schools example without body{position:relative}
[w3schoolScrollspyexampledelposition:relative](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GF0JY0HCDGSK)
it work just fine

Can anyone please explain to me why the above example works even without body {position:relative}?

Answer (score 0):

Body tag doesn't require `position:relative` to work, as it already covers the entire view port. In fact,  defaults to `position:static`, much like any other element, and  defaults to `position:relative`, which does all the work.
The `<body>` tag doesn't need any `position:relative` to work, it is just needed mandatorily in elements other than  tag, and this is mentioned in W3Schools documentation for BootStrap4 scrollspy.

Have a look at it here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp